# relative accidentals

Tags: lilypond, accidentals

Is it possible to let lilypond print a sharp symbol when a flat in the key signature is canceled (and a flat to cancel a sharp) and a natural symbol othewise?

So for example in F major a B would be preceded by a sharp symbol, but from E-flat back to E it'd use a natural symbol. This was used in the 17th century and I can't find anything about it in the lilypond reference manuals.

Comment: You don't *let* LilyPond do anything:  you **tell** it what to do. If you want to precede a new key sig with naturals, just write them in.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft The question isn't about naturals before a key signature change; it's about how key signature sharps and flats are cancelled for accidentals. There doesn't seem to be an `\accidentalStyle` for the behaviour the questioner wants.

Comment: @DanHulme so isn't the answer the same: you need to either create a minimacro or just manually write the desired accidental?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I think that people who would be happy with overriding all the accidentals by hand are not the kind of people who use Lilypond. It might be possible to make a new `\accidentalStyle` to do it, but I don't know enough about the internals to know where to start.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft People come here for specific answers, not blanket "well there is a way to do it, go forth and figure it out".

Comment: @Dave which is why I didn't post an answer!  Here's a presumably useful link:   http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.19/Documentation/extending/new-markup-command-definition

Comment: @CarlWitthoft No, but you did bother comment to a new user in  a manner that isn't really helpful, and may be construed as mildly insulting.

Comment: In F major, to sharpen the *Bb*, wouldn't it have a natural sign? If it gets written *as* B#, it'll sound like C, and should probably be written as such.

Comment: @Tim the whole point of the question is that what you describe is the modern convention, but in the 17th century they wrote music differently! In fact, some chromatic chord progressions in J S Bach were completely misunderstood (i.e. they considered to be just typos) for the first century or so after Bach's music was "rediscovered", because nobody remembered this old notation convention, even though it was explained in contemporary textbooks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since playback is very low in Lilypond's priorities, the easiest way to do this is to actually create a "B sharp" in the score where you would conventionally see a "B natural". Presumably the only reason you want to do this is to reproduce exactly what was in some 17th century source, not for performance - either by computers or modern humans.

If you are creating a short musical example the simplest way would be just to enter the "B sharp" using the conventions of your chosen input language.

Alternatively, you could define a new language (or edit an existing one) in the file `define-note-names.scm`. For example, the definition of English note names in that file contains

```
        ...
        (bflatflat . ,(ly:make-pitch -1 6 DOUBLE-FLAT))
        (bflat . ,(ly:make-pitch -1 6 FLAT))
        (b . ,(ly:make-pitch -1 6 NATURAL))
        (bsharp . ,(ly:make-pitch -1 6 SHARP))
        (bsharpsharp . ,(ly:make-pitch -1 6 DOUBLE-SHARP))
        ...
```

It's should be fairly obvious how to change that to make "b" in the `.ly` input file create something that looks like a "B sharp" in the score.

If you define your own input language, you could get correct playback from the same `.ly` file by generating a MIDI file using the standard language definitions.

Comment: wow, thanks. I hadn't thought of diving into the config files. Do you know a way to conditionally pick a definition based on the current key signature? Can I just put a check in with the note definition, or does it have to go someplace else.